# After Java update, Juniper VPN site is not recognizing that Java is installed

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, vpn, java, juniper

I am using Chrome with an updated Java (v. 10.51.2.13, SE7 U51). Before the updated Java, I was able to get on my job's VPN without any issues. Now, after logging in, I get this prompt:

[image]

I clicked run, and then I am lead to this screen:

[image]

It automatically started downloading *JuniperSetupClientInstaller.exe*. I never had this happen before but, just in case, I ran it and it completed fine. I then went back and attempted to login again but the same exact thing happened.

Not sure what steps I should take to troubleshoot this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found the fix:

1. Go to your Java Contro Panel (i.e., "Configure Java" shortcut).
2. Go to "Security" tab
3. On the bottom, click "Edit Site List..."
4. Add the URL of your VPN without any path, e.g.: https://www.example.com
5. Click okay.

When you're done, your security tab should look something like this:

[image]

Hope this helps. Got to the solution via [Juniper's KB](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB28704).

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same issue this morning. Try deleting the temporary internet files within your java control panel. Worked for me.

Comment: Got my hopes up but that did not work. Thanks for the suggestion though.